# How can I capture streaming video from broadcast tv website?

Tags: mac, video, streaming, screen-capture

Soon a conference will be broadcast on one website.

How can I capture live streaming from my web browser?

Broadcast site: http://msu1.broadcastnow.ru/

And I am using Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with the free http://www.gregion.com or http://camstudio.org